# jqColorPicker Javascript plugin

Tags: color-picker

We are trying to place multiple instances of the jqColorPicker on a single page, but only the first one that is initialized seems to only work.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: could you give the link of the color-picker used and a sample of your code on http://jsfiddle.net/  ?

Comment: Yes, the link is : http://dematte.at/tinyColorPicker

Comment: I'll need the code that don't work too, as it seem you should be able to use multiple instant (so it's in your code)